# Javascript Regex for .ts extentions

Tags: javascript, regex

Could you please give me a javascript regex which match all .ts files except the files ending with page.ts and d.ts

ex :

- home.inventory.ts -> match
- player.ts -> match
- book.page.ts -> not match
- component.d.ts -> not match

Comment: Dot needs to be escaped.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Why do you need a regex? `.endsWith('.ts') && !.endsWith('.page.ts') && !.endsWith('.d.ts')` would be easy enough in most cases, no?

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead to prevent `*.d.ts` and `*.page.ts` from matching.

```
/^(?!.*(page|d)\.ts$).*\.ts$/
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ NEGATIVE LOOKAHEAD
```